# get name of failed constraints

Tags: validation, grails, groovy, grails-orm

Assume I have a `User` class that has a `username` property and there are several constraints defined on this field.

```
class User {
    String username

    static constraints = {
        username blank: false, unique: true, email: true
    }
}
```

If I call

```
user.save()
```

I can then figure out if any of the constraints on the `username` field failed via

```
user.errors['username'] != null
```

But is there a way I can figure out which of the constraints failed?

Comment: Not sure you can... Might be able to work it out from `user.errors['username'].code` ?

Answer (score 2):

The value `user.errors['username'].codes` will contain a number of keys used for looking up validation messages in `messages.properties`.  You can use these to figure out which constraints broke.

For example, `user.errors['username'].codes[-1]` will contain the constraint part of the `messages.properties` key:

```
assert user.errors['username'].codes[-1] == 'blank' // if blank constraint fails
assert user.errors['username'].codes[-1] == 'unique' // if unique constraint fails
```

Answer (score 2):

Yeap, you can check the error code with `code` property on the error object:

```
def user = new User(email: '')
user.validate()
assert user.errors['email'].code == 'blank'

user.email = 'asdasd'
user.validate()
assert user.errors['email'].code == 'email.invalid'
```

If you may have more than one error in a property, the only way i found to get all the errors for that property is to iterate the `allErrors` property:

```
class Foo {
    String bar, baz
    static constraints = {
        bar blank: false
        baz email: true, notEqual: 'foobar'
    }
}

def foo = new Foo(bar: '', baz: 'foobar')
foo.validate()
foo.errors.allErrors.each {
    println "$it.field: $it.code"
}
```

Should output something like:

```
bar: blank
baz: notEqual
baz: email.invalid
```